# Ajax request not save form data when add woocommerce hook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, woocommerce

I customized the `form-edit-account.php` template by adding ajax requests to save data without page refresh. It works fine, the data is saved correctly. The problem occurs when the hook `woocommerce_save_account_details_errors` is added. This hook allows to view error messages when form fields are not respected, or view success messages if all fields are fine. Why does adding that hook break the save form data?

**In functions.php**
I have this function which allows me to save data. However, if I add `add_action('woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','save_account_details', 10, 1 );` for message display, data saving does not work.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );
function save_account_details() {

  if (trim($_POST['account_first_name']) == '') {
    $response = wc_print_notices();
  } else {
    $response = "Settings Saved!";
  }

  // Don't forget to exit at the end of processing
  echo json_encode($response);
  exit();

}
```

**Js at the end of the form**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
  $('.mts-edit-account').on('submit', function(e) { //form onsubmit ecent
    e.preventDefault(); // the preventDefault function stop default form action

    //Ajax function save settings
    jQuery.ajax({
      type: "post",
      data: jQuery(".mts-edit-account").serialize(),
      url: "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
      success: function(data) {
        $('.woocommerce-notices-wrapper').html(data);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, we needed to add array with var to the hook `&$errors` `&$user`

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', array( &$errors, &$user ), 1, 10 );

add_action( 'wp_ajax_save_account_details', 'save_account_details' );

function save_account_details( $user_id ) {
  if (trim($_POST['account_first_name']) == '') {
      wc_add_notice("<b>Nome</b> è un campo obbligatorio", "error");
      $response = wc_print_notices();
    } else if ( isset( $_POST['account_first_name'] ) ) {
      wc_add_notice("Modifiche salvate con successo", "success");
      $response = wc_print_notices();
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit();
}
```